# Batch copy and reopen itself on new location

Tags: batch-file, path, copy, environment-variables

My batch script can not be run from network source, that's why it's gonna make a copy of itself to the desktop and starts the new copy, on finish it's deleting the copy.

```
:: Check location
    if "%~dp0" == "%userprofile%\Desktop\" goto:eof
    xcopy /I /Y "%~dpnx0" "%userprofile%\Desktop\" >nul 2>&1
    start "new window" cmd /c %userprofile%\Desktop\batchname.bat
    exit
```

That works fine, my issue is, %cd% or %0 is not updated and is still acting like the original script. Shows the location of the original script.

How can I check the location, make a self-copy to the desktop and start it, like it was double-clicked within windows? Because the script only fails, if it's started through the original script of the share.

What happens:

- Starting script XYZ.bat from network share
- Script notices not being located on desktop
- Script does self-copy to desktop
- Script runs copy from desktop
- Script ends
- Copy launched from original script
- Script located on desktop >> fine
- Script reads infos of script header:

  `for /F "tokens=3-8 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /B /C:"::    Drive:" "%~dpnx0"') do (`
- Script fails because %~dpnx0 contains path of original script which is unavailable because all network shares are removed at this point

Any suggestions?
PS: I'm new here, I hope my English is understandable. Cheers

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the help, the thing with the path is fixed now and the script works fine, as long as I don't turn on the "remove all existing drives" function. If I do so the following happens:

Previous steps taken:
Script checks location and copy itself to the users desktop and starts from there, also all drives are removed, than it fails on the findstr thingy with the error:

- [Drive-Mapper:]  All map drives removed
- [Drive-Mapper:]  Mapping drives now:
- Das aktuelle Verzeichnis ist ungültig. **The current
  folder does not exist**
- [Drive-Mapper:]  Successfully finished **<< I wish..**
- Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . . **Press any key to continue**

The Mapping function:

```
:mapdrives
    %say% Mapping drives now:
    set errorcount=0
        for /F "tokens=3-8 delims=  " %%a in ('findstr /B /L /C:":: Drive:" "%~f0"') do (
            REM echo Server=%%a User=%%b Letter=%%c drive=%%d nick=%%e
            REM if "%%b" == "all" OR if "%%b" == "%username%" (
            if "%%b" == "all" (
                >nul 2>&1 net use %%c: \\%%a\%%d /persistent:yes
                if errorlevel 1 (%say2% Failed %%c: \\%%a\%%d & set /a errorcount=errorcount+1) else (
                    if "%%e" == "" (
                        :: Rename without nick
                        >nul 2>&1 reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##%%a#%%d /v _LabelFromReg /d "%%d (%%a)" /f
                        %say2% Successfully %%c: \\%%a\%%d
                    ) else (
                        :: Rename with nick
                        >nul 2>&1 reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##%%a#%%d /v _LabelFromReg /d "%%e (%%a)" /f
                        %say2% Successfully %%c: \\%%a\%%d @ %%e
                    )
                )
            )
            if "%%b" == "%username%" (
                >nul 2>&1 net use %%c: \\%%a\%%d /persistent:yes
                if errorlevel 1 (%say2% Failed %%c: \\%%a\%%d & set /a errorcount=errorcount+1) else (
                    if "%%e" == "" (
                        :: Rename without nick
                        >nul 2>&1 reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##%%a#%%d /v _LabelFromReg /d "%%d (%%a)" /f
                        %say2% Successfully %%c: \\%%a\%%d
                    ) else (
                        :: Rename with nick
                        >nul 2>&1 reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##%%a#%%d /v _LabelFromReg /d "%%e (%%a)" /f
                        %say2% Successfully %%c: \\%%a\%%d @ %%e
                    )
                )
            )
        %sf_wait2%
        )
    %sf_wait%
    if "%errorcount%" == "0" (%say% Successfully finished) else (%say% Warning %errorcount% Errors!!)
    %say2% & pause
goto:eof
```

Script crabs infos from batch header:

```
    :: - Force - Deleting drives        (0=No,1=Yes)
        set force_del_drives=1
    :: - Force - Kill Explorer          (0=No,1=Yes)
        set force_kill_explorer=1
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: HINT     SERVER      USER    LETER   DRIVE       NICKNAME (IF NOT USING DRIVENAME)
::  Drive:  server  all     H       Home        My Home
::  Drive:  server  all     V       Drive1
::  Drive:  server  all     M       Drive2
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::  -Drive: server  user    I       DisabledDrive
::  Drive:  server  user    K       Drive4
::  Drive:  server  user    Z       Homes       All Homes
```

PS: If I run the script from c:\ it will copy itself to desktop and runs perfectly, it also works like I said, if I dont remove the network drive the script originaly was executed from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the `for /f` line as it stands in your posted code. The code you've provided runs perfectly.

Comment: `Script fails because %~dpnx0 contains path of original script` This assumption is simply wrong. `%~dpnx0` or shorter `%~f0` represents  the currently running batch

Comment: Related: [Self-moving batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42861154).

Comment: The *findstr* string is `::<space>Drive:` while your *script crabs infos* is `::<space><space>Drive:` where `<space>` is an actual space. Do not understand how the *findstr thingy* relates to any of the errors you mention.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Check location
if not exist "%userprofile%\Desktop\" (
    >&2 echo Desktop folder not exist
    exit /b 1
)
if "%~dp0" == "%userprofile%\Desktop\" goto :main
xcopy /I /Y "%~f0" "%userprofile%\Desktop\" >nul 2>&1
start "new window" "cmd /c "%userprofile%\Desktop\%~nx0""
goto :eof

:main
echo %~f0
pause
goto :eof
```

Added check for *Desktop* folder as it is a *Shell Folder* and may
not exist in that location.

Logic changed to go to :main label if location is *Desktop* folder.

Command of `start` modified to handle the script name and extension
without hard coding a name and extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the thing with the path is fixed now and the script works fine, as long as I don't turn on the "remove all existing drives" function. Do you maybe have also a solution for this?

Comment: The information you have given is not enough to solve all the issues you may have. I do not know what the "*remove all existing drives*" function is, what the main code calling these functions is. Suggest you run the code with `echo on` and redirect *stdout* and *stderr* to file and find the errors. The line following the error line is usually the issue.